# Tomcat - Access properties from JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, properties

I am using Spring. A properties placeholder is used to access all properties in the application. I would like to use it also in JSP pages.

I found some solutions using Spring-MVC but I do not use it. I uses a `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet` that I could overwrite in my web.xml if necessary.

Is it possible to somehow expose the properties to the JSP code without having to overwrite the `ServletContextListener` class ? (like it was done in [this article](http://j2eecookbook.blogspot.com/2007/07/accessing-properties-loaded-via-spring.html))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject the property into your controller/servlet, then add that value to your model. Access that attribute as you would any other :

```
@Value("${myProperty.setting}")
private String whateverYouWantToCallIt;
```

then :

```
model.addAttribute("mySetting", whateverYouWantToCallIt);
```

and in JSP :

```
<span>${mySetting}</span>
```

And if its just a text message used in lots of places you could use [message.properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4864487/106261).

Comment: I do not use any controller (no Spring-MVC), it is just plain JSP.

Comment: why is your question tagged spring then ?

Comment: I would like to inject the PropertyPlaceHolder from my Spring configuration in the Servlet in order to use spring properties in my JSP pages. I do not know if Spring provides an easy way to do that out-of-the-box.

Comment: inject it as I said, then set session attribute instead of adding to model

Comment: I used a `ServletContextListener` to inject all the properties as ApplicationContext attributes. However, when I use `<span>${mySetting}</span>` the token is not replaced by its value. What component is responsible to perform this transformation ? (It works when I call `this.getServletConfig().getServletContext().getAttribute("mySetting");`)

Comment: If the property is in the session, as @NimChimpsky suggested in his comment, you should use `${sessionScope.myStting}`

Comment: I used methods as indicates in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123657/how-can-i-share-a-variable-or-object-between-two-or-more-servlets

Comment: I succedded to use ${mySetting} by enabling EL using `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038046/enabling-el-in-jsp