# Spring JSP passing variables

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I want to handle simple form. Here's form from my signUp.jsp, where from I receive my data

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="user-entity" action="process.html">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="userName">Name:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form:label path="label">Age:</form:label></td>
        <td><form:label path="label"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>  
</form:form>
```

And part of my result.jsp

```
<p>User's name is ${user.userName}. The age is ${user.age}.</p>
```

And UserController.java

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/signUp")
        public ModelAndView signUpPage() {
            return new ModelAndView("signUp", "user-entity", new User());
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/process")
        public ModelAndView processUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
            model.setViewName("result");
            model.addObject("user", user);
            return model;
        }

    }
```

As the result I get

`User's name is ${user.userName}. The age is ${user.password}.`
and i have no idea why. Where might be the problem?

Comment: can you post your result.jsp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing 
`<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` in result.jsp

Solution brought from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038046/enabling-el-in-jsp)